# Como remover somente o elemento pai, sem retirar os filhos

Tags: jquery

Como remover somente o elemento pai, **sem** remover também os elementos filhos com jQuery. Tendo essa estrutura por exemplo:

```
<a href="#">
    <p>A</p>
    <p>B</p>
    <p>C</p>
</a>
```

Com a intenção de remover o pai(), após a função a estrutura ficaria desta forma:

```
<p>A</p>
<p>B</p>
<p>C</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a função `unwrap()` no jQuery.

Para efeitos de teste criei um botão que faça a simulação.

```js
$('.ativar').on('click', function(){
  if($('p').parent().is('a'))
    $('p').unwrap();
  else
    $('p').wrap('<a href="#"></a>');    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#">
  <p>A</p>
  <p>B</p>
  <p>C</p>
</a>

<button class="ativar">Ativar/Desativar</button>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Outra alternativa seria pegar o conteúdo e dar um replace:

```js
var children = $("a").contents();
$("a").replaceWith(children);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#">
    <p>A</p>
    <p>B</p>
    <p>C</p>
</a>
```